# Switch GNOME Terminal Profile from the command line

Tags: linux, terminal, profile, gnome

If I'm running gnome-terminal with multiple tabs open, is it possible to switch the profile of a given tab at the bash prompt, with instant effect, and without altering the profile of the other tabs?

I understand how to use gconftool or gconftool-2 to change elements of a profile (such as the background), but I don't know how to actually switch the profile for a specific tab or window.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: it would be nice to have rules to switch prodile according to the prompt/title

Answer (score 5):

It does not answer your question in particular, but since it might help others, I leave it here regardless.

If there was a way to change the current profile, you could have different profiles for each tab.

You can list all existing profiles using:

```
gconftool-2 --all-dirs /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles
```

You can get the current profile using:

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/global/default_profile
```

And you can set a new default profile (`solarized-light` in this case) using:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/gnome-terminal/global/default_profile solarized-light
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this through gconf-editor which maintains the settings for everything in gnome. See the gconf-editor [manual](http://www.gnome.org/~bmsmith/gconf-docs/C/index.html) and section on [gnome-terminal](http://www.gnome.org/~bmsmith/gconf-docs/C/gnome-terminal.html).

From the terminal, you can make changes with [gconftool-2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess my issue is that if I use gconftool-2 to alter the background of 1 tab's profile, this affects the background of all the other tabs too. If I set each tab to use a different profile, then there's no way of each tab knowing which profile its on. A bit of a catch 22 :)

Comment: This kind of thing seems lacking with gnome software, I heard a similar complaint about having separate desktop wallpapers. This might be something that will be fixed eventually due to demand though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar, I think it could help you 
to use `gnome-terminal --help`
which will show you some commands you can use to open terminal with certain profiles 
you will need to figure out how to write the line at prompt to open with the tabs and profiles you want ....once you have the hard part figured out you can add the line to your 
bashrc

Run `nano ~/.bashrc` to open up the bash configuration file, which gets run every time you open a terminal. Then add the line to the bottom save and close.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is about GNOME Terminal and the command line, it's worth knowing that MATE Terminal (a GNOME Terminal fork) allows profile switching via a simple keyboard shortcut.